# .htaccess RewriteRule works but Redirect 301 does not

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, htaccess

I have launched a new version of a website on a new domain. On the old domain I have redirected traffic to the new domain with a global RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for most pages. Now I am doing individual 301 redirects to correct some pages that have changed addresses, but they don't seem to work.

I am trying to redirect `oldsite.com/login` and `oldsite.com/profile` to `newsite.com/my-account`

Here is the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

# This RewriteRule works
RewriteRule ^login$ https://www.newsite.com/my-account/ [L,R=301,NC]

# this Redirect 301 does not
Redirect 301 /profile https://www.newsite.com/my-account/

# Global rewrite rule
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am correctly redirected from `oldsite.com/login` to `newsite.com/my-account` by the RewriteRule.

When I visit `oldsite.com/profile` I go to `newsite.com/profile` instead of `newsite.com/my-account`. The Redirect 301 does not work and the global RedirectRule is activated.

I can't figure out what is going on!
It's an up to date Cent OS 7 server with Virtualmin.

Any ideas why `Redirect 301` is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems RewriteRule is always executed before Redirect inspite of the order in the .htaccess file, so the global RewriteRule is always executed before the redirect rules.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856193/using-mod-rewrite-and-mod-alias-redirect-301-together-in-htaccess